# How do I use a range slider value as a var?

Tags: html, rangeslider

How do I code script that compares a a range slider value with 49. If more than 49 if shows true, if less than 50 displays false.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="var1" step="1">
```

Comment: Step 1, by making sure the attribute names are in red, and the values in blue..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want something to change while when the user changes the slider, try this

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("number").onchange=function() {
    document.getElementById("rngnum").innerHTML=this.value<49?"False":"True";
  }
  document.getElementById("number").onchange(); // trigger when loaded
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" id="number" step="1" value="50"><label for="number" id="rngnum"></label>
```

If you just need to interrogate it:

```
var lessthan49=parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value)>49?true:false;
```